# Can an Angular NgModule provide a style.scss file to be used by whoever imports it?

Tags: angular

I want to create an Angular (v7) NgModule to aggregate some Angular Material modules and use it as a library in my applications:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatSelectModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MatSelectModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],

})

export class MaterialCustomModule {  }
```

I also want to package a styles.scss file to then import it in my application styles file:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Some other common styles I want to have in this module
```

And finally use it in my application styles.scss:

```css
// import my custom style here somehow.
```

This shared module is built using ng-packagr:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/shared",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  }
}
```

I built my module using "ng build" but the result does not contain the styles file.

Can this be done? Have a styles file packed together a module and used in a parent module?

Comment: You will have to copy the assets file and place it in the dist location using `ng build`
Heres something I used in my package.json `"build": "npm run build:lib && npm run copy:assets", "build:lib": "ng build path/to/lib", "copy:assets": "cp -r ./projects/path/to/src/lib/assets ./dist/path/to/assets"`

Comment: @shahidfoyit kind of worked, but image urls are not being resolved. Ng serve fails: Can't resolve '../images/logo.png'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using both @shahidfoy and @Joffrey K suggestions, I achieved the following:

1. I created an assets folder in my library;
2. I configured package.json to copy those assets into the final
   package;
3. In my application's angular.json, I added a new entry in the styles,
   and assets part.

Answer (score 0):

export CSS from `module.ts` seems to be a bad aproach, it's only supported at component level. The workaround would be to have single css file referred by all module components.

however, you could define an Angular library with specific styles files, install it then add styles to your `angular.json` :

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/pathToYourCustomLib/style.css"
        ],
```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question. This module is being built with ng-packagr and it doesn't have an angular.json.

Comment: Oh ok, but why not try to create an Angular library with CLI ? it will use ng-packagr as well. You can find a good example here https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/angular-libraries